# USPS shipping method does not display for Canada in checkout - magento 1.9.3.7

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, usps

Can anyone please help me USPS methods is not shown when I select Canada from backend and I have to set allowing shipping to this country please help me.

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of the configuration changes you did for setting USPS based on allowed countries, also I didn't understand your question properly, did you mean to say USPS shipping method is not displaying on checkout step even when correct address is added for Canada?